# how to grep an exact string which has a variable

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

I have a file like below and I want to search only `"this[*]: world * seconds"` where `*` means a variable

```
sudo cat log | grep "world" | grep this -m1
Apr 26 04:19:12 : SESSION = 111, from_remote_host = , USER = root, PWD = /root, CMD = 2018-04-26 04:19:12 sudo cat log | grep "world" | grep this -m10
Apr 26 04:18:45 xxxx aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa: SESSION = 101675, from_remote_host = jjjjjjj, USER = root, PWD = /root, CMD = 2018-04-26 04:18:45 sudo cat log | grep "world" | grep this -m1
Apr 26 04:11:54 xxxx this[98461]: world 29.93 seconds
Apr 26 03:41:50 xxxx this[77844]: world 18.87 seconds
Apr 26 03:11:36 xxxx this[58682]: world 18.60 seconds
Apr 26 02:42:29 xxxx this[43432]: world 34.56 seconds
```

Comment: I was trying to search like this but I am getting the entire file.Can someone please help.

    cat log | grep "world" | grep this

Answer (score 1):

I think this line will do what you want:

```
grep -E 'this\[[0-9]+\]: world [0-9.]+ seconds' file
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much

Comment: I don't know how come the downvote... this does exactly what OP wanted: `"this[*]: world * seconds" `